# laravel No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid

Tags: php, ssl, laravel-5

I am building a project using Laravel. It was working fine on localhost, but when I upload it to the server (the server has comodo ssl installed), I receive the following error:

```
RuntimeException in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 29:
No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid
in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 29
at EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\Encryption\{closure}(object(Application), array()) in Container.php line 733
at Container->build(object(Closure), array()) in Container.php line 626
at Container->make('encrypter', array()) in Application.php line 674
at Application->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter') in Container.php line 837
at Container->resolveClass(object(ReflectionParameter)) in Container.php line 800
at Container->getDependencies(array(object(ReflectionParameter)), array()) in Container.php line 771
at Container->build('SahraSalon\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies', array()) in Container.php line 626
at Container->make('SahraSalon\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies', array()) in Application.php line 674
at Application->make('SahraSalon\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies') in Pipeline.php line 123
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 118
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 86
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Can anyone help solve this error?

Comment: I too have this issue now, more worst http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505809/no-supported-encrypter-found-issue?noredirect=1#

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Do you have all the necessary extensions installed on the server?

- PHP >= 5.5.9
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension
- Tokenizer PHP Extension

It could be that you're missing the OpenSSL extension. Also, do you have the key set in `.env` file?

---

Try running:

`php artisan key:generate`

---

Answer: the `'cipher' => ''` was not set.

Comment: .env value : 
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=zK7sr9SzegGEDFClzJDs0vAkpO8NvjZA

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

Comment: Is your `'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC'` in `config/app.php`

Comment: And run `php artisan key:generate` to generate a new key.

Comment: @Rahmanza I have all those extensions, changed my cipher type and used `php artisan key:generate` to try to fix the problem but it persists. Could my routes have anything to do with this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('/login', 'PublicController@login');

    Route::post('/login', 'AuthenticationController@login');

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {

        route::get('dashboard', function() {
            echo 'in dash';
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 98):

You only type in console:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

And if your app.php not change this Key, change manually.

---

Next if you should then happen to get this error message:

> [ErrorException]
>     file_get_contents(/path/to/my/project/.env): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Then make a copy of the `.env.example` file and try again:

```
cp .env.example .env
php artisan key:generate
```

Comment: And check if you have all necessary extensions installed.

Comment: before copy .env.example to .env

Answer (score 10):

I fixed it by running this:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: In my case, I was using Deployer for the first time. When I was symlinking the project to the /current folder, I got the encryption error. Creating the cache file fixed it.

Answer (score 9):

I have same issue before and I fixed it follow this way:
Go to config/app.php, 
change `"cipher" => "anything"` to

```
'cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
```

Comment: the default value is `'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',` but this should be without quote!! Strange.

Comment: That helped me too, I wasn't having `AES-256-CBC` in the list of supported ciphers as it turned out from `phpinfo()`

Answer (score 7):

I just fix error.

1. `Shift+Click` right mouse to "open commend window here" from your root project.
2. In console write: `"php artisan key:generate"`.
3. Get 32 character 'Mark' to `config/app.php` like `'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'insert get 32 char key')`,//line number 81

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I need to enable mcrypt extension.

But first, check if you already have it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y mcrypt php5-mcrypt
```

Check if mcrypt module is loaded:

```
$ php -m | grep mcrypt
```

if nothing shows, is because is not loaded, but you already have installed above right? So do this:

```
$ php5enmod mcrypt
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Check again and you should see mcrypt instead of nothing. Thats a good sign, reload you app and go fix your next error ;)

```
$ php -m | grep mcrypt
mcrypt
```

Answer (score 5):

In root directory, if there is `.env.example` file then change it to `.env` and then run `php artisan key:generate`. This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

write in console `php artisan key:generate`

you will get message like: `Application key [get 32 char key] set successfully.`

replace app key in `config/app.php` like `'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'insert get 32 char key'),//line number 81`

Comment: Sorry, I'm using **WAMP** but I don't know were is located the `config/app.php` file. Could you let me know it?

Comment: first , you go you `project folder` in `wamp server` and then you find `config` folder then you will get `app.php` . thank you

Answer (score 4):

solved with:

```bash
php artisan key:generate
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are using app.php configuration file instead of reading key from .env file, then you can remove the env() function on key variable, ex:

```
'key' = env('someRandom36CharsString'),
```

to

```
'key' = 'someRandom36CharsString',
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve deployment to live Ubuntu server, here is all the steps

Ensure PHP >= 5.5.9

Ensure, OpenSSL, Mbstring, Tokenizer and mcrypt is installed.

To Install mcrypt in PHP (Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt,
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

Make storage folder writable:

```
chmod -R 0777 storage
```

Make Apache use the Lavarel /public folder as home:

```
DocumentRoot /home/code2/public_html/Laravel-Project/public
    <Directory "/home/code2/public_html/Laravel-Project/public”> 
         AllowOverride all 
    </Directory>
```

Major gotcha for me is FTP might not copy hidden files by default:
    `.env` and `/public/.htaccess` need to be there!

After completing the tasks above, it worked on Ubuntu server

Answer (score 1):

I was suffering with this problem for a few too many hours before I discovered that the key was being cached in the bootstrap\cache\config.php. Deleted the file and my site loaded fine (i.e. there was otherwise *no* problem with my config).

I discovered this by adding some debug output to boostrap\cache\compiled.php to make it spit out the cipher and key (somewhere around line 7010). Then dug around to see how it was picking up the config and found it uses a cache config file.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have this [requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation) in your machine.

1. PHP >= 5.6.4
2. OpenSSL PHP Extension
3. PDO PHP Extension
4. Mbstring PHP Extension
5. Tokenizer PHP Extension
6. XML PHP Extension

Then after install or updating your project by

> composer update

After this you have--

> .env.example

Make a duplicate and rename it to--

> .env

and make changes according to your database configuration or any other modifications you need.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=your db name
DB_USERNAME=username if any otherwise root
DB_PASSWORD= your password if not set leave blank
```

Finally generate your application key by--

> php artisan key:generate

For Someone may be only last step is enough. But I have this problem every time I clone any laravel project. This whole step makes this with any hazard.

Answer (score 0):

Add `"illuminate/html": "~5.0"` to require section of your `composer.json` file. Just like this:

```
...
"require": {
    ...
    "illuminate/html": "~5.0"
    ...
},
...
```

Then run `composer install` command. When `composer install` gets complete. run `php artisan key:generate`. You will get a message like this:

```
Application key [get 32 char key] set successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

In some old versions of laravel you have to change the default value of cipher in `/config/app.php` from "AES-256-CBC" to "AES-128-CBC".

the default cipher in confing/app.php is "AES-256-CBC" which needs a 32 character string, and the cipher "AES-128-CBC" only needs 16 characters.

Entering `php artisan key:generate` is the simplest solution.

new versions

```
 'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

old versions

```
 'cipher' => 'AES-128-CBC',
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use "" Quotation marks with the values inside the .env file or OS envs.

Avoid `APP_KEY_CIPHER="AES-256-CBC"`
instead use `APP_KEY_CIPHER=AES-256-CBC`.