# RuntimeException in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 29: No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, heroku, runtime

PLEASE DON'T THINK OF THIS AS A DUPLICATE.

I have looked at about every other post about this error and none of them worked.  I am using Heroku to push and a little bit ago it was working perfectly. 
  I have done key:generate with 256, using 'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC'. 
  It is working fine in localhost, but not in Heroku after I push it.
  I have tried about every solution out there, I have to be missing something, this is frustrating.  What I don't understand is that even if I am generating the key, but still...
  Please, help me find a way to fix this error. 
  Also, this is what I am getting as the error output:

```
    in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 29
    at EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\Encryption\{closure}(object(Application), array()) in Container.php line 734
    at Container->build(object(Closure), array()) in Container.php line 627
    at Container->make('encrypter', array()) in Application.php line 674
    at Application->make('encrypter') in Container.php line 838
    at Container->resolveClass(object(ReflectionParameter)) in Container.php line 801
    at Container->getDependencies(array(object(ReflectionParameter)), array()) in Container.php line 770
    at Container->build('Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies', array()) in Container.php line 627
    at Container->make('Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies', array()) in Application.php line 674


 at Application->make('Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies') in Pipeline.php line 123
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
Thanks
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512970/laravel-no-supported-encrypter-found-the-cipher-and-or-key-length-are-invalid)

Comment: With no code the only answer is in the error message. Add your code along with full error information. do you have `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` or `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` set, that is setting the block size, not the key size. What are you using for a key and what she is it?

Comment: I have edited my post with the whole output of the error. Also, @limonte , I have already tried that solution before and it did not help

Answer (score 3):

You can try to run

```
 php artisan key:generate
```

in the client,and replace the APP_KEY in the .env file using the generated key.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that different encryption libraries are installed between your local and Heroku. There are 2 similar underlying encryption libraries, openssl and mcrypt. It's possible that one of the two is installed on your local and the other on Heroku. There are a few differences between the two, the most obvious is that the mcrypt library has the Rijndael encryption modes but openssl has AES. The two are functionally equivalent but have different names.

I would recommend that you use openssl in preference to mcrypt as it has been maintained more recently.

php -m will reveal which modules are installed.

Assuming that you have openssl installed, you should be using the AES-256-CBC mode and you will need a 32 character key (256 bits), no more, no less.

Comment: I am not too sure how to check, but I checked with php -m and I do see openssl, not mcrypt, therefore, I believe I am using openssl. Also, I am using AES-256-CBC. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use The Command 
                 php artisan key:generate

And replace it with APP_KEY in .env file of your laravel project.

It Worked For Me.