# laravel: No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, encryption, laravel-artisan

I created a new laravel application and didn't write any custome code.
All I did is running the following command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

which migrated the default user table that came with laravel.
and then ran the command:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

now the homepage is the default homepage of laravel but when I click on login or register I get:

> RuntimeException in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 31: 
>   No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.

still learning laravel so I want to figure out how the auth works and how to customize it. but it seems that even the default has a problem which I can't solve.

Comment: probably u should run php artisan key:generate

Comment: already did that, and the key available in the  .env is the same as the key in the app.php config . and the 'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC'

Comment: also try php artisan cache:clear....

Comment: unfortunately, same problem

Answer (score 3):

From command line enter `php artisan key:generate`
Check solutions here: [laravel No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512970/laravel-no-supported-encrypter-found-the-cipher-and-or-key-length-are-invalid)

Answer (score 1):

In config\app.php change:

`'cipher' => 'whatever it is'`,

to

```
'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```