# No supported encrypter found issue

Tags: php, encryption, laravel-5

When i post my form on my laravel (5.2) i get this when it has to return some value to the former page.

**MY CONTROLLER**

```
class WsRegisterController extends Controller{

public function register()
{
    $wsregistration = Input::all();
    $wsUserName = Input::get('name');
    $wsUserEmail = Input::get('email');
    $wsUserPassword = Input::get('password');

    /* Check if user is a bot */

    $wsrules = [
    // 'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|recaptcha', capthcha
    'name'   => 'required|min:2|max:32',
    'email'  => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'required|alpha_num|min:8'
    ];

    $wsvalidator = Validator::make($wsregistration, $wsrules);

    if ($wsvalidator->passes()) {

        /* Check if the email address exits */

        $wsUser_count = User::where('email', '=', $wsUserEmail)->count();

        // return $wsUser_count; exit;

        if ( $wsUser_count > 1 ) {

            return Redirect::to('/test')->with(array('error_msg' => 'This email address exist, please use another email address.'));

        }
     }
   }
  }
```

So i tried stackoverflowing it with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512970/laravel-no-supported-encrypter-found-the-cipher-and-or-key-length-are-invalid) but it is still not working

**CONFIG/APP.PHP FILE**

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Encryption Key
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
| to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
| will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
|
*/

'key' => env('o/tPhyhKmuLoJMWXZeV8b10OFoCT62z6WKuC3HO5Jbw='),// env('9TSL9BsEjZyoM9BjX9du0XaLnCDi4m4Z'),

'cipher' => 'AES-128-CBC',//'AES-256-CBC',
```

**.ENV FILE**

```
APP_KEY=base64:o/tPhyhKmuLoJMWXZeV8b10OFoCT62z6WKuC3HO5Jbw=
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

I even did this artisan command to generate new key `php artisan key:generate` please what did i do wrong @everyone.

[No supported encrypter found error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EXnb.png)

Comment: For AES-128-CBC, your key needs to be 16 characters of random data. Yours is 32. Switch to AES-256-CBC and you'll probably fix this problem. Also, make sure the OpenSSL extension is installed.

Comment: I would suggest looking in the **Linked** and **Related** question on the right-hand-side of this page. There are some usefull suggestions in there.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski thanks for the support but the issues still exists, i have Switch to AES-256-CBC  with this key "MzKfrO9x6D32y6YJE9dX6RtDRIg5PnGsGVab9AIefpU=" but the error still occur.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @everyone for your support but i have solved it.

```
'key' => '9TSL9BsEjZyoM9BjX9du0XaLnCDi4m4Z',// env('9TSL9BsEjZyoM9BjX9du0XaLnCDi4m4Z'), 'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

**php artisan config:cache**

Did the magic.