# Laravel returning RuntimeException error log randomly

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My application works great. But if I happen to make a request several times throughout, either ajax or randomly pages, I get the following error:

```
local.ERROR: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.' in C:\wamp\www\application\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider.php:29
```

This happens randomly and in both local and production environments.

My current setup:

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomString'),

'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

.env file includes: `APP_KEY=eyckMXzoR8AeurnkpBBQ8k2Ryp0zo21l`

I've tried: `php artisan key:generate` but the problem still continues. Has anyone else had a similar issue?

Comment: Interesting... Hard to debug this issue. You might need to edit `EncryptionServiceProvider.php` and log a bit of information about what `$key` and `$cipher` is when it throws

Comment: do you have a special setup like distributed environment oder some special file system? (blind guess)

Comment: similar to : http://stackoverflow.com/a/31513179/4757316

Comment: I have the same issue... did you solve it?

Comment: i'm also having this exact same problem... nothing special in my setup, just a small application on a single apache server... did you find your way through?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the `APP_KEY` value from your .env file and use it on the `app.php` file too replacing the value `SomeRandomString`.