# How to fix - RuntimeException in Encrypter.php line 43

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

**App.php - File**

> This is my App,php file

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

**.env - File**

> This is my .env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:CETuLOZZZi5QEEYXhyCO/O7l7fhM6LI5clvsT59cgTM=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ads
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=null



PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_KEY=
PUSHER_SECRET=
```

**Error was:**

```
> RuntimeException in Encrypter.php line 43: The only supported ciphers
> are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.
```

> Developers please help me to solve this problems. 
>   Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running `php artisan config:clear` ?

Comment: The `APP_KEY` value is wrong. try `php artisan key:generate` to generate a new key

Comment: Your key is too short, in PHP key size use either 16, 24 or 32 byte keys for AES-128, 192 and 256 respectively, I'm not sure how Larval handles it though...

Comment: Have you tried manually edited Encrypter.php. Included $cipher = 'AES-256-CBC'' in __construct? See more [here](http://laravel.io/forum/06-04-2015-cipher-error)

Comment: the key length seem to be right but, the thing that you put base64: before increases the required key length, remove base64:

Comment: You need to use `php artisan key:generate`.
This link will help you to understand whats going wrong. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512970/laravel-no-supported-encrypter-found-the-cipher-and-or-key-length-are-invalid

Comment: @ka_lin yes i cleared config still it's not working bro

Comment: @MateiMihai bro new key is already generated

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix how can create a long dynamic keys?

Comment: @SalihMohamed - if you have PHP7 you can use this  http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php

Answer (score 7):

You only type in cmd:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Answer (score 5):

The way I did it was I ran `php artisan key:generate`. I then copied the output in the brackets, and put in my **.env file** as **APP_KEY=base64:keygoesherenotpostingmyrealkey**. I did `php artisan config:clear`, then `php artisan config:cache`, and things are now working!

Answer (score 0):

Check to ensure you `.env` file has value in `APP_KEY`, if not and you just ***created a new project*** or ***cloned a project***, you will need to run `php artisan key:generate` in your console or terminal.