# Internal Server error 500 in Angular + Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, angularjs-http

I am developing a application using laravel and angular js. Laravel is for the api and the view is also in a blade template which includes a ng-view element.
I get this "internal server error 500" error once in a while when making $http requests.
 
the request is working most of the times, but it's frequent, like 1 out of 10 times i get this error. Please explain the correct way to resolve this issue.

Comment: Need more information. Are there no error-logs in /storage folder of Laravel?

Comment: sorry i didn't no about the logs, actually there are lot of errors in the laravel.log file, following are the last once:   
  
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\resume_builder\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(2373): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Illuminate\\Cook...')
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\resume_builder\public\index.php(58): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->terminate(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Http\Response))
#11 {main}

Comment: I don't think that is the complete stacktrace, seeing as it begins at #9

Comment: basic on http post methods, the Internal Server error show when the command[post] or params[get] not correct or api is down, but in your case is only about loading files. for better understanding use $timeout when you connect to API, please try i'm wating.

Comment: Hi, i'm currently using $q, which i saw how to do on youtube. this is how my code look currently: [link] (http://prntscr.com/cxhlbc), would you be able to refer me to a place where i can see how to do the same with $timeout

Comment: @Maher by the way, i temporary solved it using another service to refresh the browser for five times untile the 500 goes away, I think it's bad practice, but that works for now, please let me know your thoughts on it too, thanks.
[link](http://prntscr.com/cxhnn5)

Comment: 500 means INTERNAL SERVER ERROR -> check your XAMPP stack logs (apache most likely). Most likely you have some kind of permission problem.

Comment: as i mentioned, i don't get the error all the time, it works fine about 90% of the times, but not the other 10%, as Maher said, I think this is to do with timing, I have got this issue also on the live servers too, with angular + laravel. I think this is probably to do with the way i'm handling http in angular, but i couldn't find a proper solution yet

Comment: @Bmax, did you use postman application for connect to API?

Comment: @Maher Yes, i do not get any errors when i connect with postman, it only comes when i use angular $http methods

Comment: Hi this is the response i get, when i check the network tab [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjzJOX)

Comment: Hi bro, did you see this link [laravel No supported encrypter found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512970/laravel-no-supported-encrypter-found-the-cipher-and-or-key-length-are-invalid)