# production.ERROR: RuntimeException: No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, ubuntu-16.04

I run my laravel 5.2  app on nginx ubuntu xenial (digital ocean)

Image don't upload in my production app whereas at localhost it works fine.

In my laravel log following error is shown :

```
>     production.ERROR: RuntimeException: No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.in
> /var/www/laravel/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:7771 Stack trace:
> #0 /var/www/laravel/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(7761): Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider->getEncrypterForKeyAndCipher(NULL,
> 'AES-256-CBC')
```

ans so on ..

How do i resolve it.

Comment: You've probably done this since your application seems to be working, but just checking: `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: @Loek yes i've done this :(

Comment: Then we're in config hell. Check out this thread, it contains most of the solutions to this problem (since there are tons of reasons why this happens) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512970/laravel-no-supported-encrypter-found-the-cipher-and-or-key-length-are-invalid?rq=1

Comment: @Loek tried everything  still not resolve :(

Comment: And that's why it's config hell... You could try to clear your compiled class file and create a new one: `php artisan clear-compiled && php artisan optimize`

Comment: @Loek did it . Now??

Comment: Test if it works now? :p If not, I'm out of solutions and you should probably place a bounty on this or be prepared to debug a few hours to see what exactly is happening

Comment: @YaShChaudhary I'm also having this issue

Comment: @Growler sorry didnt remember what i did...maybe reupload everything and doing composer install !