# Key Generate No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid

Tags: laravel, heroku, laravel-5

2 and try build my app in Heroku, but i'm having a problem with the APP_KEY

`php artisan key:generate`

the problem its always generate key that longer than 32 char, for example `zrkythusOVoNBAnqrjGaL9RxX2VUOTwK3y5q4Sbaf5s=`

so i try to change the the chiper to AES-128-CBC, it only generate 24 char, not 16 not 32

I try to push with the generated key and it throw me `RuntimeException in /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 45:` and `No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.`

Here is my app config

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'base64:zrkythusOVoNBAnqrjGaL9RxX2VUOTwK3y5q4Sbaf5s='),

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC'
```

try the alternative

```
'key' => 'base64:zrkythusOVoNBAnqrjGaL9RxX2VUOTwK3y5q4Sbaf5s=',

        'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

result is the same

Did i missed something?

Comment: Ensure PHP >= 5.5.9 also Ensure, OpenSSL, Mbstring, Tokenizer and mcrypt is installed.

Comment: Try the first script in this page, so that you know what are the openssl cipher methods available in your machine: http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-get-cipher-methods.php

Comment: Why not able to set the key in the env file

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512970/laravel-no-supported-encrypter-found-the-cipher-and-or-key-length-are-invalid

Answer (score 0):

When you run `php artisan key:generate`, it updates the `.env` file with a new `APP_KEY`. It's likely that whatever key you have in the `.env` file is overwriting the key you're setting using the `app.php` config.

If the key is base64 encoded, like your example, it's allowed to be more than 32 characters. If you decode the key, it should be <= 32 characters.